# Where are the save files for Incredipede?

Tags: incredipede

Where can I find the save files for the game Incredipede?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the save files can be found in the following directory (replacing `[USERNAME]` with the name you use to log into Windows, **not** Steam):

```
C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\com.northwayGames.Incredipede\Local Store\#SharedObjects
```

You can get to that directory quickly by entering the following into the start menu search bar:

```
%APPDATA%\com.northwayGames.Incredipede\Local Store\#SharedObjects
```

This save folder is the same for both the *Gog.com* and the *Steam* versions of the game (and will be shared by them if you have both versions installed).

**NOTE:** These are stored as [Flash Shared Objects](http://www.adobe.com/security/flashplayer/articles/lso/), and can therefore not be easily viewed or edited with text editors. You can back up and restore the entire folder, but trying to edit them manually may result in a corrupted save file.